# Make an array key => value adding values from another array

Tags: php, arrays, google-calendar-api

I want  this array output because I need it for the attendees of the Google_service_calendar_event in PHP:

```
   Array ( 
         [0] => Array ( [email] => myemail@gmail.com ) 
         [1] => Array ( [email] => myemail1@gmail.com )
         [2] => Array ( [email] => myemail2@gmail.com )
         [3] => Array ( [email] => myemail3@yahoo.com ) )
```

This is my code PHP:

```
    $invitados_inicial = array(array('email' => $correo_del_director));

    foreach ($_SESSION['gcal_correo_aplicantes'] as $correo_aplica) {

        $invitados_inicial['email'] = $correo_aplica;
    }
```

And this is what I get (NOT what I need):

```
    Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [email] => myemail@gmail.com ) 
        [email] => Array ( 
            [0] => myemail1@gmail.com 
            [1] => myemail2@gmail.com 
            [2] => myemail3@yahoo.com
        ) 
    )
```

Anyways, I don't get my desired output array and I can't my attendees into the Google_service_calendar_event.   How should I do for getting my disired array output?

Comment: Hello, try `$invitados_inicial[] = ['email' => $correo_aplica];`

Comment: @marv255, it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2):

You have to clarify the structure of `$_SESSION['gcal_correo_aplicantes']` to get the right answer. In the following, I assumed it was something like :

```
$session = array( "email1@add.com","email2@add.com");
```

First solution :

```
<?php
$invitados_inicial=[];
for ($i=0; $i<count($session);$i++) {
    $invitados_inicial[$i] = array( 'email' => $session[$i] );
}
var_dump($invitados_inicial);
```

Second option :

```
<?php
$invitados_inicial=[];
foreach ($session as $correo_aplica) {
    $invitados_inicial[] = array( 'email' => $session[$i] );
}
var_dump($invitados_inicial);
```

Comment: $_SESSION['gcal_correo_aplicantes'] is a POST variable of a multiple select input (HTLM select with multiple choices of a simple list).  If I do a print_r of this variable I get this: 
array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(27) "myemail@gmail.com" [1]=> string(27) "myemail2@gmail.com" [2]=> string(23) "myemail3@gmail.com" } }  and the I tried your code and it's not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 $invitados_inicial = array(array('email' => $correo_del_director));

        foreach ($_SESSION['gcal_correo_aplicantes'] as $correo_aplica) {

             foreach ($correo_aplica as $value) {
               $arr['email'] = $value;
               $invitados_inicial[] =  $arr;
           }
        }
```

Comment: what is the output?

Comment: this is the output: Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => myemail@gmail.com ) [1] => Array ( [email] => Array ( [0] => myemail2@gmail.com [1] => myemail3@gmail.com [2] => myemail4@gmail.com ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, you gave me ideas and I could fix it doing this:

```
    $invitados_inicial = array(array('email' => $correo_del_director));

    // Agrego a los candidatos seleccionados a listado de participantes      
    foreach ($_SESSION['gcal_correo_aplicantes'][0] as $correo_aplica) {

      $invitados_inicial[] = array('email' => $correo_aplica);
    }
```

Thanks to Jarbit Lira and Carlos E. López, they help me a lot too.